# ¿Existe algún caso de sustantivo que proceda de una forma conjugada de un verbo?

Tags: verbos, solicitud-de-término, sustantivos

Es conocido que los infinitivos de los verbos pueden generar sustantivos. Así, podemos decir *su [andar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2ZIziL7) pausado*, e incluso pluralizar el infinitivo y decir *del cerdo me gustan hasta sus andares*. Igualmente, de los participios se generan adjetivos (acabo de descubrir *colorado*, que originalmente viene de *colorar*, "dar color") e incluso sustantivos también: *las [idas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KtHnYZs) y [venidas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bXk0MKK)*.

Sin embargo, el otro día se nos dio en el *translation-golf* un caso de licencia poética que consistió en algo parecido a esto (no fue exactamente así, lo cambio para plantear mejor la pregunta):

> Original: *I wander the seemingly dark future.*
>   Traducción: *Vago por el oscuro será.*

En la búsqueda de un sinónimo de *futuro* se planteó el uso de *será* como sustantivo, usando la tercera persona del singular del futuro de *ser*. Dejando de lado la posible validez de la licencia poética, quería aprovechar para preguntar:

¿Existe en el diccionario recogido algún caso como el descrito, de alguna forma verbal conjugada en un tiempo con persona y número, que se haya convertido en un sustantivo? Si no, ¿existe en algún corpus de referencia (CORDE/CREA o similar) algún caso de licencia poética similar a la descrita?

En un principio sopesé la posibilidad de la primera persona del indicativo (`pasar > yo paso > un paso`), pero en estos casos la dirección suele ser al revés: del sustantivo se crea el verbo (`paso > pasar` al igual que `tuit > tuitear`).

Comment: A veces puede ser difícil determinar qué vino primero.  Según el DLE, pasear viene de paso + ear y no de paseo que vienen del verbo.  Pasar y paso llegaron al español simultáneamente del latín, aunque en este vino primero passus.  Pero una palabra que muy obviamente viene de un verbo conjugado tendría que ser **vaivén**

Comment: *vaiven* son dos verbos igual que *correveidile* que son tres y otras palabras compuestas que contienen al menos un verbo como *saltamontes*, *correcaminos*, etc. pero no se me ocurre ninguna que no sea compuesta

Comment: @guifa buena palabra, aunque más que un verbo son dos: "va y ven", ¿hay algún caso que provenga de un único verbo?

Comment: Ah, claro.  Un **recibí**

Comment: @guifa muy bueno!

Comment: @guifa pues ya puedes ir poniendo eso como respuesta. :-)

Comment: Contaría un *sanseacabó?

Comment: @guifa preferiría palabras que sean simplemente un verbo conjugado. La de "recibí" me ha gustado mucho, puedes destacarla en la respuesta, y luego ya si quieres incluir otras como "sanseacabó", "vaivén" y demás, me parece estupendo.

Comment: creo que hay muchos sustantivos que nacen de verbos, sobre todo los que indican profesion :

Andador, Comprador, Comedor, Reparador, Lavadora,

Comment: @Erin casi todos esos ejemplos si se aplican a personas son adjetivos y la pregunta era sobre verbos conjugados.

Comment: No sé si esto viene al caso: *la mira*.

Comment: ¿Sirve "la ida", "la venida"?

Comment: @MauricioMartinez esos ya los comento en el texto de la pregunta.

Answer (score 8):

***[pagaré](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RRtG8qr)*** 1. m. Papel de obligación por una cantidad que ha de pagarse a tiempo determinado.

Answer (score 7):

He aquí varios ejemplos

- **[recibí](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VQqFgpI)**
  **1.** *m.* Fórmula que, situada delante de la firma en ciertos documentos, expresa que se ha recibido lo que en ellos se indica.
- **[abonaré](http://dle.rae.es/?id=08LZSqv)**
  **1.** *m.* pagaré.
- **[cúmplase](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BfkIWne)**
  **1.** *m.* Decreto que se ponía en el título de los funcionarios públicos para que pudiesen tomar posesión del cargo o destino que se
  les había conferido. **2.** *m.* Fórmula que ponen los presidentes de
  algunas repúblicas americanas al pie de las leyes cuando se publican.
- **[pase](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S3crNF0)**
  **1.** *m.* Permiso que da una autoridad para usar un privilegio, licencia o gracia. **2.** *m.* salvoconducto (‖ documento). **3.** *m.* Licencia que permite el libre tránsito de personas o cosas por diversos lugares a fin de realizar ciertas actividades. **4.** *m.* pase que da el Estado a los rescriptos y bulas pontificias y a los agentes extranjeros.

Comment: No sé si es demostrable, pero es posible que los términos legales _decreto_, _visto_ y _considerando_ también pertenece a esta clase. Aunque su morfología no permite descartar otros orígenes, su nombre parece venir de las respectivas fórmulas, en que son usados sintácticamente como forma verbal

Comment: *Visto* y *considerando* no son formas conjugadas.

Comment: @pablodf76 son conjugaciones, solo que no son personales.