# ¿Hay palabras similares a "acabóse"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, historia

La palabra "acabose" tiene la siguiente entrada en el DLE:

> [**acabose**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=0FWOKaJ)
>
> De *acabó* y *se<sup>1</sup>.*
>
> **ser** algo **el acabose**
>
> 1. *loc. verb*. Denota que ha llegado a su último extremo. U. m. en sent. peyor.

Me causa curiosidad lo que dice de: "De *acabó* y *se*". Viéndolo así podría pensar que otras palabras también pueden componerse con "se" para formar una nueva palabra, pero no se me ocurre ninguna. ¿Fue este un caso único, con alguna razón particular?

En una tira cómica, [Mafalda](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mafalda), el personaje principal "compone" unos términos de construcción parecida: *continuóse* y *empezóse*. Acá entiendo que su uso es humorístico, pero, ¿podrían ser válidas estas palabras?

[image]

Comment: Habiendo visto solo el título de la pregunta ya se me había venido a la cabeza esa tira de Mafalda. Qué gracia me ha hecho cuando la he visto... :-D

Comment: Creo que tuvimos ya una pregunta sobre la construcción de sustantivos a base de verbos conjugados plenamente en forma personal (tipo *el recibí*, etc) pero no la encuentro de momento.  Encontramos una docena de palabras parecidas.

Comment: @guifa ¿Será esta? [¿Existe algún caso de sustantivo que proceda de una forma conjugada de un verbo?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/25567/1674)

Comment: Mirando en el DLE palabras que terminan en *-ose* veo pocas y casi todas ellas de la forma _Acción y efecto de..._ como con [desglose](https://dle.rae.es/?id=D1MVCAl),

Comment: También creo que es de notar que en la ortografía moderna, ya no se tildan estas palabras

Comment: Existe también [*cúmplase*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=BfkIWne), si bien es solamente el imperativo del pronominal _cumplirse_.

Answer (score 4):

Parece que estamos ante un caso único. Como ha notado @fedorqui en su comentario, hay muy pocas palabras en el diccionario que acaben en *-ose*, y todas significan "acción y efecto de", como la "acción y efecto de desglosar" que es *[desglose](https://dle.rae.es/?id=D1MVCAl)*.

Esta forma de construir tiempos verbales era muy común en la antigüedad: *encontróse con él*, *partióse la casa*, *llegóse a él*, *murióse don Donato*, *dexóse caer*, *erguióse todo derecho*...

Por supuesto, el verbo *acabar* no escapa a esto:

> *E acabose la agua dela botija, e echo al fijo deyuso de vno delos arboles.* (c. 1400)

El caso de *acabóse* es curioso, porque se usaba como fórmula para cerrar cartas, escritos y demás, como "Acabóse el día tal", y para indicar que no había nada más que hacer o decir:

> *[...] y haciendo lo que quisiese, haría mi gusto; y haciendo mi gusto, estaría contento; y en estando uno contento, no tiene más que desear; y no teniendo más que desear, acabóse, y el estado venga, y a Dios y veámonos, como dijo un ciego a otro.*
>
> Miguel de Cervantes Saavedra, "El ingenioso hidalgo don Quijote de la Mancha", 1605.

La palabra aparece reflejada en el *Henríquez* de 1679 (traducida al latín), y luego ya en el *Academia usual* de 1817, reflejando el uso comentado:

> ACABÓSE. loc. fam. No hay mas que hacer ni decir.

Curiosidad: no es la única conjugación de *acabar* que entra en el diccionario. Véanse:

> ACABÁRAMOS. f. fam. con que se da á entender el gusto que se recibe cuando despues de gran dilacion se logra alguna cosa ó se sale de una duda.
>
> SANSEACABÓ. expr. fam. con que se da por terminado un asunto.

Pero sigamos. En este punto la locución es verbal, se usa la palabra como verbo pero de una forma que sugiere un significado distinto del verbo original, de ahí su entrada en el diccionario. Sin embargo, los primeros casos de su uso como sustantivo los encuentro en la segunda mitad del siglo XIX:

> *Don Robustiano se acercó al Magistral; miró a todos los rincones a todas las puertas, y con la mano delante de la boca, dijo:*
>
> *—¡Aquello es el acabóse!*
>
> Clarín (Leopoldo Alas), "La Regenta", 1884-1885.

De hecho, en 1901 el *Toro y Gómez* define la expresión como "el fin, lo último, la de vámonos". Y en 1925 ya se define en el DLE como "frase con que se denota haber llegado una cosa a su último extremo". Y añade que se usa "para denotar ruina, desolación o desastre".

Ya como reflexión personal, entiendo que el éxito que tuvo esta palabra es que se construyó usando un verbo que denota extremos en el transcurso del tiempo. No me imagino cualquier otro verbo con una construcción similar: *el comióse*, *el subióse*, ¿qué significarían? En cambio, *el acabóse* funciona muy bien, y precisamente ese es también el éxito del chiste de Quino, que juega con verbos similares que denotan el transcurso del tiempo para dar lugar a *el continuóse* y *el empezóse*. Un genio.

Por último, notar que la *Gramática* de la RAE incluye *acabose* en un grupo de palabras compuestas formadas "lexicalizando un grupo verbal de estructura compleja" que suelen "contener pronombres, artículos, preposiciones y otros elementos: *acabose, [besalamano](https://dle.rae.es/?id=5P6ZzUZ), [bienmesabe](https://dle.rae.es/?id=5UME3xF), [curalotodo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=BiORpTD), [hazmerreír](https://dle.rae.es/?id=K3szhNW), mataporgusto, [metomentodo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=P7jc6jo), [parlaembalde](https://dle.rae.es/?id=RwtE550), [pésame](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Sm6AMQp), [quehacer](https://dle.rae.es/?id=UlraVzO), [sabelotodo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Wsustft), [siguemepollo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=XrrmDYH), [tentempié](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ZUM7MgT), [tentetieso](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ZUMSIFm)*".

Comment: Es fácil imaginar que en algún universo alternativo que existiría un sufijo *-(i)ose* para representar la realización de alguna acción (y seguramente terminaciones como *-cion* tendría raíces parecidas aunque no tenemos constancia fija de sus orígenes más allá del latín)

Comment: En cierto modo, *pésame* es una respuesta a la pregunta, pues también es un sustantivo formado por forma verbal personal + enclítico, aunque en este caso no sea un reflexivo.

Comment: @Gorpik - Estoy de acuerdo.  También el *válgame*, el último ejemplo de la lista.  Pero se pueden construir frases con otros ejemplos no tan estándares, sin demasiado esfuerzo: "¿Ya mero llegamos al vámonos?" "Mamá, mamá, ¡ya llegamos al casémosnos!"  (No sé cómo escribir esto -- no se pronunciaría la segunda S en *casémosnos*.)

Comment: @aparente001 Según la RAE, la s de la primera persona del plural se elimina al usar el enclítico -> *casémonos*. De todos modos, ese *válgame* me parece que no pinta mucho en la lista, porque no es un sustantivo. Los otros que mencionas, en efecto, podemos sustantivar cualquier palabra; pero no tienen (o han tenido) un uso habitual como las otras que menciona Charlie.

Comment: @Gorpik pues tienes razón, "válgame" no es un sustantivo, curioso que se le haya pasado eso a la RAE. ¿Habremos encontrado un bug en su gramática?

Comment: @Charlie Pues no; más bien hemos encontrado una edición incorrecta que ha hecho otro usuario en tu respuesta. La lista de ejemplos de la Gramática de la RAE no incluye *válgame*.

Comment: @Gorpik pues dado que es una cita literal, fuera.

Comment: @Gorpik - gracias y gracias.